# Scientific notation in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-formatting, numbering, cell-format

I need make a number format similar to scientific notation, but without E nor e. Just classic like this:

[image]

(In latex it's `2.3\times10^3`)

Maybe Excel doesn't support this format.

(I have on mind Number Format - for hundreds numbers - not in math formula)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use html.  Type this into Notepad

```
<html>2.34 x 10<sup>-5</sup> + 5.67 x 10<sup>-6</html>
```

Copy it and, in Excel, Paste Special - Unicode.  It will render whatever html you have.  You won't be able to edit it in Excel though.

Comment: See also http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/02/23/html-in-cells-ii/

Comment: Great idea. So in excel:
    ="<html>"&B6/(10^ROUND(LOG10(ABS(B6));0))&" x 10<sup>"&ROUND(LOG10(ABS(B6));0)&"</sup></html>"

then result copy into notepad and copy back to excel. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Excel doesn't support that number format.

I think you need to use a formula, like this:

```
=A1/(10^ROUND(LOG10(ABS(A1)),0))&" x 10^"&ROUND(LOG10(ABS(A1)),0)
```

Comment: Nice. But dont produce typographically correct output. Result is "0,9994 x 10^1". How I can replace ^1 by really top index 1?

Comment: You'd have to write a macro if you want to get rid of the `^` and have the exponent be superscript.

Comment: Thanks for help. I cannot select 2 accepted answers. Its weird, because solutions is combination of yours and dkusleika tips.

Comment: @Vojtech, No problem...I think his answer is pretty cool. You can give us both an upvote though if you like. (Click the arrow above the gray number for each question).

Comment: you can use [Unicode superscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) ⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹ to have a top number instead of `^`

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best location for this question, but these links might help:

http://peltiertech.com/Excel/NumberFormats.html

http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/CustomFormats.htm

I have used both sites as a reference when dealing with Excel stuff in the past.